# Hyper-V Limitations

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

With Hyper-V on a host machine, what are the upper limitations of the virtualization?  1 VM per proc?  What about memory and networking utilization?  Do the upper bounds change when choosing Full vs. Server Core as the host machine?  If anyone can point me to the official documentation on physical and practical limitations I would be very grateful, I couldn't find any with my searching but I'm guessing it's got to be out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/faq.aspx) with some details, including:  "Hyper-V Server supports systems with up to 4 processors with 1, 2 or 4 cores." "Hyper-V Server supports up to 32 GB of physical memory." etc

There's also an interesting point [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/49123/hyper-v-and-12-vms) regarding licensing differences when choosing between Standard & Enterprise.

I don't *believe* you lose any functionality with Full vs. Core - but definitely with Standard vs. Enterprise vs. Datacenter.  For example, Enterprise is the minimum version you'll need to support live migration (VM move between HyperV servers without downtime) - with R2.

Comment: Enterprise and Datacenter versions support up to 2TB of ram. 
The R2 version also ups the 32GB limit on standard from what I've heard but I've yet to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

**About 4 CPU core limit:**

In VM's config file section:

[processors]
[count type=”integer”]8[/count]

Now you have 8 core CPU.

**What others say:**

> To verify my results I ran NuclearMC on a VM with 1 core, 4 cores, and
>   8 cores dedicated to the virtual machine.
>
> 1 core      4 cores       8 cores
>
> Fibonachi              5875       23392         46075
>
> Factorial                4177       19714         37091
>
> Ferma                     4132        16791         34300
>
> Sort                          2582       12277         25434
>
> Hyperbolic           3533        12081         16405
>
> Digit e                     3896        10147         14348
>
> Picture Morph    3305        8653            12508
>
> Prime                      3583        13896          28276

[image: And my screenshot]

Comment: That is false info no matter how many times you post it. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Here it works with my AMD 1090T?

Comment: Well, then! I take back my -1! That's crazy that they don't prevent that. The word from MS people is that the HyperV scheduler got crazy unstable with 6 or 8 core VMs so they stopped testing it or trying to optimize for it. I still wouldn't trust it under load if you have more than 1 VM configured that way. But... coool. ;-)

Comment: that is straight up bananas

Answer (score 0):

The only hard limit I've seen is that you can't allocate more RAM to VMs than you have physical RAM available.  With CPU (if you don't allot minimum CPU usage for a VM) and network, it's a question of what performance is acceptable.